# In Laravel 9, how do I get the Illuminate/Mail/Message, to call embedData(), without a blade file?

Tags: laravel, email, laravel-9

We're using Laravel 9, and we store email template in our database, not in blade files.

When sending an email, we would like to use the `embedData()` function on the `Illuminate/Mail/Message` class, but how do we get this message object?

We have a class that extends `Illuminate\Mail\Mailable`, called `App\Mail\Message`.

We send mail like this:

```
$message = new App\Mail\Message($subject, $fullBody, $fromAddress, $replyTo, $attachments);
$message->to($address)->from($fromAddress, $fromName);
Mail::send($message);
```

But we want the Illuminate/Mail/Message message object, because we want the embed function.  How can we get this object?

Answer (score 0):

Use mail raw and if the template is in blade syntax, you can parse it using the `Blade` class.

```php
$template = Template::find(11); // get the template from db
$templateBody = $template->body; // or whatever the template body attribute is
$templateRender = Blade::render($templateBody); // render body via blade engine

Mail::raw($templateRender, function (Message $message) {
    $message->subject('Hello, world!');
    $message->to('steve@apple.com');
    // add other stuff to the message here...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In our app/Mail/Message::build() function, we ran this to get the $message object:

```
return $this->withSymfonyMessage(function (Email $message) {
  // here is the $message object
});
```